# Multiple OLS estimation TypeError

Tags: python, finance, estimation, quantitative-finance, economics

I am trying to do some Newey-West OLS with statsmodels on my data to estimate my parameters, and the following is my code for doing so:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division 
import xlrd as xl
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import statsmodels.api as sm

file_loc = "/Python/dataset_3.xlsx"
workbook = xl.open_workbook(file_loc)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
tot = sheet.nrows
data = [[sheet.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in 

range(sheet.nrows)]

rv1 = []
rv5 = []
rv22 = []
rv1fcast = []
T = []
price = []
time = []
retnor = []

for i in range(1, tot):        
    t = data[i][0]
    ret = data[i][1]
    ret5 = data[i][2]
    ret22 = data[i][3]
    ret1_1 = data[i][4]
    retn = data[i][5]
    t = xl.xldate_as_tuple(t, 0)
    rv1.append(ret)
    rv5.append(ret5)
    rv22.append(ret22)
    rv1fcast.append(ret1_1)
    retnor.append(retn)
    T.append(t)

df = pd.DataFrame({'RVFCAST':rv1fcast, 'RV1':rv1, 'RV5':rv5, 'RV22':rv22,})
df = df[df.RV1.notnull()]
model = smf.OLS(formula = 'df.RVFCAST ~ df.RV1 + df.RV5 + df.RV22', data = df)
```

Everything looks just fine when I look at the arrays or my dataframe, but it returns just: TypeError: **init**() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

I have tried a bunch of different methods and I cannot see what I am missing.

When i run it the following errormessage shows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Python/harrv.py in <module>()
     41 df = df[df.RV1.notnull()]
     42 
---> 43 model = smf.OLS(formula = 'df.RVFCAST ~ df.RV1 + df.RV5 + df.RV22', data = df)
     44 
     45 #mdl = model.get_robustcov_results(cov_type='HAC',maxlags=1)

TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

printing rv1 gives you:

```
Out[318]: 
[0.015538008996147568,
 0.008881670570720125,
 0.010421778063375802,    
.....    
 0.003151044550868834,
 0.0029676428110974166,
 0.005236329928710288,
 0.004838460533164701,
 '']
```

And the other rv gives similair floating numbers. The df just assembles them in the manner that pd.dataframe does, which according to the documentation is supported (http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/example_formulas.html).

Comment: It would help if you would write the actual error message including the  stack trace. From your current description it is not clear what call crashes.

Comment: There it is. But I cannot see what more kinds of arguments could be needed, since I took this method from another example, which worked for that person. 
I was thinking, could it be because of the existence of single-quotes in the lists?

Comment: Using `df.` for the formula argument is clearly wrong. (Compare with http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/example_formulas.html). But I admit that I don't see a correlation between the error message and your arguments. It would help if you could make the example self contained. E.g. add `import` statements and example data.

Comment: Fixed. I hope the rv1 example will suffice because the other are assembled in the same manner and are just floats aswell.

Comment: After changing the df. part of the formula the same error message still shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the formula function in statsmodels.formula.api is lower case. Upper case OLS is the same as in the main statsmodels.api. The uppercase models will be deleted in future from the formula.api namespace to avoid exactly this confusion.

That means, you need to use lower case ols, as in

`model = smf.ols(formula = 'df.RVFCAST ~ df.RV1 + df.RV5 + df.RV22', data = df)`

Note, the lower case formula functions are just aliases to the `from_formula` methods of the models.

`smf.ols` is a shortcut for `sm.OLS.from_formula`

Comment: That worked! But when I try to print a summary of the fitted model, it returns an error about the axis needing to be specified when shapes of a and weights differ. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: I have no guess for that without the traceback or a full example. You could ask a new question or ask at the pystatsmodels google group. One thing: drop the `df.` inside the formula string. We (statsmodels developers) never considered this pattern, and I'm not sure it works correctly. It is likely that it messes up `patsy`s creation of the design matrix, or post-estimation handling.

Comment: I posted a second question with more detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799161/summary-not-working-for-ols-estimation